# MS Chart Forecasting

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, mschart

I would like to build a chart (Using MSchart ,C# & ASP.Net) to show the current values and based on the current values I must show the trend in the next 2 years .Somewhat like a prediction.

Sample Scenario is

In 2013 , a company has got 10 projects.In 2014 , got 15 Projects &
in 2015 , got 14 Projects.

Now our real job is to find out the expecting Project Count in 2016 & 2017. 
We must show the project count & year in a chart

Pls help.

Thanks,
Sreedevi

Comment: what exactly is your problem? making the prediction or binding the values to chart?

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing some function fitting, for your example you could try a linear fitting: given the line function y=mx+q you find the m and q parameters so that the most of your data points are in th output of the function.